# Elastic ip address is not assigning automatically on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos6, elastic-ip

I followed this blog to automate elastic Ip address on AWS.

[http://www.idevelopment.info/data/AWS/AWS_Tips/AWS_Management/AWS_14.shtml#About%20the%20Author][1]

I completed all the steps.But the Ip address is not assigning automatically.Any help would be highly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I think a little more information is required. Are there any error reports (logs/terminal/AWS's logs).

Amazon's free tier only supports up to 5 elastic IP addresses (If I recall correctly) - is it possible you are using more than this?

If not on the free tier, what tier are you using? How many addresses are provided through said tier and how many are you presently using?

Is this machine within a private subnet (where Elastic IP's aren't granted)?

Comment: There is no error I'm seeing.As per the blog I have completed all the steps.At the end I tried to start the instance it should be assigning the ip.But unfortunately it was not assigned.                                                   I'm using micro instance have 5 elastic ips .i'm trying to automating the existing ip to associate with the instance.